# CSS apply in ajax success response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to apply the following CSS in ajax success response for status Actually I am creating wishlist heart icon color changes based on click and remove. I apply color CSS but now I want to add the following CSS.Code is not working due to overwrite of css color.
if `status == 2` apply following CSS:

```
.remove {
  background-position: -1680px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(7);
  animation: remove-from-wishlist 1s steps(7);
}
@keyframes remove-from-wishlist {
  0% {
    background-position: -1320px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1680px 0;
  }
}
```

If `status == 3` apply following CSS:

```
.add {
  animation: add-to-wishlist 1s steps(22);
  background-position: -1320px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(22);
}
@keyframes remove-from-wishlist {
  0% {
    background-position: -1320px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1680px 0;
  }
}
```

Blade file

```
  <?php 
                      if (Session::has('userid')) 
                      {
                      $userid=Session::get('userid');
                      }
                      $checklist=DB::select('select * from wishlist where user_id=? && product_id=?',[$userid,$value->sub_id]);
                      if($checklist)
                      {
                      ?>
                      <a class="sub" data-id="{{$value->sub_id}}" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart whishstate" style="float:right;color:#FBA842"></i></a>
                     <?php }
                       else
                       {
                      ?>
                       <a class="sub" data-id="{{$value->sub_id}}" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart whishstate" style="float:right;color:grey"></i></a>
                       <?php
                        }

                       ?>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sub').click(function(e) { 

    var sub_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    var input=$(this).prev();
    e.preventDefault()
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
         jQuery.ajax({

                  url: "{{ url('/add-to-wishlist') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     sub_id: sub_id,
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                    if(result.status==1)
                    {
                       window.location.href="/login";
                    }
                    else if(result.status==2)
                     {
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"grey"});
                     }
                     else if(result.status==3)
                     {
                        $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').css({"color":"#FBA842"});
                     }
                  }});

  });
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to write your CSS code in `.css` file, Then you have to just add class using `jQuery` in your ajax response just like below:

```
jQuery.ajax({

              url: "{{ url('/add-to-wishlist') }}",
              method: 'get',
              data: {
                 sub_id: sub_id,
              },
              success: function(result){
                if(result.status==1)
                {
                   window.location.href="/login";
                }
                else if(result.status==2)
                 {
                    //first remove old class
                    $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass('add');
                    $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass('remove');
                 }
                 else if(result.status==3)
                 {
                   //first remove old class
                    $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').removeClass('remove');
                    $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass('add');
                 }
              }});
```

Comment: try with a cache clear and hard refresh if everything is proper I mean the CSS file and the class name then it's working perfectly

Comment: I want to add wishlist method like flipkart when you click on heart then some animation created

Comment: It works for single anchor tag ,again  i am updating my blade code in which when i am login then it will  change color of heart again orange but this code is not apply for  multiple condition it will take color of style.plz check blade code

Comment: Jsut Try with `$('i.whishstate').addClass()` remove `a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] >` property.Please check update answer.

Comment: hello sir problem is not in your coding plz check my blade file code when i am login then i am change my style color:#FBA842 this is overwitten with our class code that is problem. Your code is work when i am not giving style and used only one anchor tab. but i am using if -else condition.

Comment: are you getting my query ??

Comment: @smitaranipatil Not exactly 
if the class is overwritten then you can use `!important` in your added css class property.

Comment: hello sir , animation can not work only color change

Answer (score 2):

You can directly add a class for it to apply CSS attached to it. Like this one

```
if(result.status==2) {

      $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass('remove ');
}

else if(result.status==3) {

    $('a[data-id="' + sub_id + '"] > i.whishstate').addClass('add');

}
```